# acmsmall normal font

Tags: fonts, acm

I am using the `acmsmall` to do an essay; I have a custom `cls` and I've re-defined all of `{title, author, etc}font` to be more appropriate. However, I am having trouble getting the normal font to be anything but 10pt. If I set `\fontsize{26}{30}\selectfont` in my document it works, but how do I get it in the `cls`?

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{essay}[2015/04/01 Essay]

\LoadClass{acmsmall}

% these don't appear to do anything
\renewcommand\@ptsize{2}
\renewcommand\normalfont{\fontsize{16}{18}}
\renewcommand\normalsize{16}
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt{26\p@}}
\renewcommand{\small}{\@setfontsize\small\@ixpt{26\p@}}
\@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt{26\p@}

% title works
\renewcommand\titlefont{\fontfamily{\sfdefault}\fontsize{16}{18}\selectfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand\paragraphfont{\fontsize{16}{18}\selectfont\itshape}

% debug
\newcommand\FontSize{{font size: \f@size~pt}}

\endinput
```

tex,

```
\documentclass{essay}
\title{Title~\FontSize}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

Normal~\FontSize.

\end{document}
```

gives,

```
Title font size: 16 pt
Normal font size: 10 pt.
```

Comment: Welcome! Please always post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to help others to help you effectively. Try `\AtBeginDocument{...}`. However, this is a hack and you should not really do it like this. Since I don't know where the class is to be found, it is hard to give a good answer. But do you really want 26pt for the default font size for an essay?

Comment: `\AtBeginDocument` hack works for me; thanks. You don't do all your documents in 26pt? :] (I wanted to differentiate between 10pt.)

Comment: **Why** are you using this class for an essay? That is, if you are not writing a paper for that journal, why are you using their class? There are more constructive exercises in frustration to be had than fighting a class which is designed to disallow just the kind of changes you want to make.

Comment: It's just so pretty.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a bug but a feature.

Publishers' styles, unlike generic `article` etc , usually do not allow the users to change  body fonts.  All papers in the given journal must have matching look.  I usually add to my classes commissioned by publishers some warnings when  the class sees an attempt to invoke options  like 12pt:  "please do not do this".

Full disclosure:  I did not write acmsmall,  but I patched it for ACM.

For a derived class you need to redefine `\normalsize`, `\small` etc.  Look how it is done in base class and change accordingly.